# How to extract the original name of a dataframe that has been renamed to a string variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been looking through other posts and cannot seem to find recommendations on how to deal with the following problem, and it's driving me crazy.

```
# Create data frame and variable for this example
data.frame(orgdf, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
a <- c(10,20,30,40)
b <- c('book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case')
c <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
d <- c(2.5, 8, 10, 7)

# Join the variables to create a data frame
orgdf <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

# Rename the data frame
newdf <- orgdf

# Plot the variables of the new data frame
plot(newdf$a, newdf$d, main = "orgdf")
```

This works if I hard code the "orgdf" into the plot title. I would like it to be able to extract the name somehow with never having to hard code it in. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `main=ls(pattern = 'df')` could help.

Comment: Why do you want "orgdf" as title when your dataframe name is `newdf` ?

Comment: I realize this may be redundant but the data frame is called in several places throughout a subsequent function I use, so I'd have to change it everywhere. I only have to specific it once this way. I am working with 50 frames at one, and call each one individually at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this might help; assuming you want multiple renamed data frames to plot using the title of the original data frame you could create your own plotting function, so you only have to hard code the name of the original data frame once:

```r
f_plot <-  function(df){
    plot(df$a, df$d, main = "orgdf")
  }


f_plot(newdf)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>